# Meaning of "Unbalanced" Tukey HSD in R with Agricolae

Tags: r, tukey-hsd-test

The `Agricolae` package in R contains a function [`HSD.test`](https://rdrr.io/cran/agricolae/man/HSD.test.html) which performs Tukey's HSD. This function has a parameter `unbalanced`, which is described as:

> TRUE or FALSE. not equal replication

My usual understanding of an unbalanced test is one with different sample sizes in each treatment. I am having trouble understanding how my understanding aligns with the documentation. What is meant by "equal replication"? Shouldn't the test be able to trivially detect if the sample sizes are different for each treatment, and behave accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, it appears that the function *does* actually know if the group sizes are equal. The `unbalanced` option isn't doing that, it's choosing between two approximations for the unbalanced case.  The relevant code lines are:

```
sdtdif<-sqrt(MSerror * 0.5*(1/means[i,4] + 1/means[j,4]))
if(unbalanced)sdtdif<-sqrt(MSerror /nr1)
```

The first, if `unbalanced` is `FALSE`, is the Tukey-Kramer approximation for unequal sample size.  The second, if `unbalanced` is `TRUE` uses the harmonic mean of all the cell sizes as the effective sample size.  If the cell sizes are all equal these two will also be equal.

A bit of searching finds [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2285936) that compares the two approaches and isn't all that enthusiastic about either one.

I agree `unbalanced` is not an ideal name for this and that the documentation is unclear.